# Workbox - workbox.cacheableResponse does not work when checking for response headers

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I have implemented the cacheableResponse for Workbox by checking the response header from the API.

However, it seems it does not cache API requests that have the `x-is-cacheable` header present on the response.

Here's how I implemented my service worker

```
const cacheableResponse = new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
    statuses: [0, 200],
    headers: {
        'x-is-cacheable': true,
    },
});

// APIs
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('https://my-api-url.here'),
  workbox.strategies.networkFirst({
    cacheName: 'api-cache',
    plugins: [
      cacheableResponse
    ]
  })
);
```

**I can confirm** that the API response header has the `x-is-cacheable: true` present and it returns the status code 200.

If I remove the `headers` then it works, however I need to filter out the specific APIs that I need to cache.

Does anyone have an idea why this solution does not work?

Answer (score 1):

So, I just discovered on **Github** that my issue is somewhat related with **CORS** and in order for the `X-Is-Cacheable` to work I also needed to add `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Is-Cacheable` in our API response (it may vary with different codebase so please refer to your API framework on how to add **response header** in to your API).

reference: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2051